Update the ICU and Timezone repositories for the AOSP on Android 9
I work on the AOSP changes for the tablet device we develop.
It's based on Android 9 system. And it should support the latest time zones.
The ICU repository we use currently:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/icu/+/refs/heads/pie-dev
The TimeZone repository:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/timezone/+/refs/heads/pie-dev
They support 2022g time zone version.
It should be updated to 2024a version which is the latest as of now.
It seems that the AOSP team does not update it or this is not the highest priority for them.
Where/how can I get the ICU and TimeZone repositories updated to 2024a time zone version?

From my current understanding Google seems to be updating Android branches for security updates, uptil 2 years, and OEMs usually backport all related features/ security updates. Check this: Manufacturer guide for long-term Android security
LineageOS developers do this for their fork, and one interesting topic here is: https://review.lineageos.org/q/topic:%22R_tzdb_2024a%22. Similar can be found for different versions.

Note there are three repos that you need to update since they all appear to have some raw timezone files in them:

system/timezone
external/icu
external/cldr (might not be strictly necessary for timezone updates?)

Here are some possible approaches:
Try LineageOS
Rajat Gupta mentions looking at LineageOS, it does appear that there are some commits posted to their gerrit that have not been merged for Pie (LineageOS 16). You would need to merge all the commits you can that are already applied and then download and apply the unmerged commits from their gerrit and hope they work, see:

https://review.lineageos.org/q/project:LineageOS%252Fandroid_system_timezone+branch:lineage-16.0
https://review.lineageos.org/q/project:LineageOS/android_external_icu+branch:lineage-16.0
I don't see any for external/cldr though, maybe not critical, who knows

Try to backport/take the patches from a slightly higher android version dev branch
Google has updated android10-dev to 2024a, notice for example this repo was updated this year to 2024a: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android10-dev:system/timezone/;bpv=1
Try to run the scripts
Google has provided python scripts in the projects and README files which can be used to download and munge the raw timezone data into the Android format. You might be able to skip the download script if you just copy only the raw input files from a higher Android version.

It is a good idea to use LineageOS repositories.
I updated my project to 2023a from LineageOS 16.0 and it works fine.

I can not use LineageOS 17.0+ since they have different ICU version and .dat file (icudt60l.dat for Android 9).
Now I need a way to request the LineageOS team to generate ICU build for Android 9 with the latest TZ 2024a. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to do this myself yet.
